# How to automate filling a simple form and clicking submit in JavaScript for a chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, forms, google-chrome, automation

Been trying to do this for days now, and have failed and have searched for examples but not found one yet that has helped.

I want to navigate through a web page by filling in the details and clicking submit programmatically.

the page is as follows:

```
<form method='post' action='login.php'>
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td>Email Address: </td>
        <td ><input type='Text' size='30' name='email'></td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>Password: </td>
        <td ><input type='password' size='30' name='password'></td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td>
        </tr><tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td  align='left'><input type='Submit' value='Log in'></td>
        </tr>
        <td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td>
        <tr><td colspan=2><hr></td></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

I cant change the above existing web page, So want to include code in a chrome extension written in JavaScript to save me heaps of time at the moment I cant get passed the login page!

I have been a programmer in the distant past but am not fully versed with JavaScript syntax yet..

One of my problems is the form does not seem to have an ID.

Could anyone help?

Thanks for the help so far but I am still struggling so have added more detail.
I have managed to do this submit in IE using VB in the past (from an Excel macro) using:

```
    Sub PressSubmit(IE)
    With IE.Document
    Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("input")
    For Each e In elems
        If (e.getAttribute("value") = "Log in") Then
            e.Click
            Exit For
        End If
    Next e

IE.Document.all("email").Value = "me@email.address"
IE.Document.all("password").Value = "myPassword"
Call PressSubmit(IE)
```

But now I need to do the same on Chrome and I am struggling with JavaScript syntax which is new to me is there anyone that could give me a JavaScript version of this, or a better version, that I can learn from by example?

Comment: _"One of my problems is the form does not seem to have an ID"_ You can use `document.forms` to retrieve all forms in `document` as an `HTMLCollection`

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I am looking... In my example how would you use it?

Comment: Define a variable referencing `document.forms`, iterate the collection and set values for the elements in each `form` in `document`

Comment: Hi Guest271314 thanks for your help so far but I am still struggling with Javascript which is a massive area to become familiar with - I was hoping for some example code, I could look at and try. I have updated my question with some more details of what I have done in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.querySelector()`, `Element.querySelector()`, `attribute selectors to set values at``elements, call`.click()`on``element to submit``

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <form method='post' action='login.php'>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Email Address: </td>
        <td>
          <input type='Text' size='30' name='email'>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password: </td>
        <td>
          <input type='password' size='30' name='password'>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td align='left'>
          <input type='submit' value='Log in'>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=2>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=2>
          <hr>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
  <script>
  var form = document.querySelector("form[action='login.php']");
  var submit = form.querySelector("input[type='submit'][value='Log in']");
  if (submit.length) {  
    form.querySelector("input[name='email']").value = "me@email.address";
    form.querySelector("input[type='password']").value = "myPassword";
    submit.click();
  }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Hi guest271314,  Thanks so much for your continued help with this. I am probably doing something wrong but cant seem to get this to work. In your code block above I inserted alert lines in the script before inside and after the If statement, and the alert inside the if statement never executes. when opened in chrome.